# How to read and store complete Objects in ArrayList from Fire DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing an app with Android Studio.

Now I would like to use the Fire DB, in order to take over the information from the data base in an Arraylist when starting the app. In this case, a node in the database should be saved as an object with its attributes.

1. The structure of the DB is still flexible. I had the plan to make a numbering of 1 and below the indexes all the attributes of one objet.
   If anything else makes sense, this can still be changed
2. How can I read these and store them in a object per index, which is then put into a Array list?

I had already found several online examples, but none got to work.

Therefore, I would be grateful for an input that I can test and then possibly discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

Please add some sample code to understand us what you do.

---

> **You need to do following things,**

---

1) Model Class which contains setter and getter methods (same name as you store in firebase)

If you multiple node inside one object then,

2) RecyclerView and RecyclerAdapter Class

3) DatabaseRefrence to access your data.

example code to retrive data from firebase

```
   final List<Certificates> list=new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Object");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Model model=snapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                list.add(model);
            }

            RecyclerAdapter adapter=new RecyclerAdapter(list,Activity.this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CertificatesActivity.this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {
            //handle error here
        }
    });
```

If you need help to understand tell me.